# OutputDebugStringAppender Not Working in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, log4net, mstest

I've followed the log4net advice [given here](http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/10/log4net-messages-in-real-time-with-debugview/).  Then I'm launching MsTest unit tests by hitting 'F5' in Visual Studio 2010.  When a unit test executes these two lines:

```
log.Warn("hello");  //this is a log4net logger.
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("there");
```

...the Visual Studio output window shows only the word "there."  Why is "hello" not output?

When I debug-hover over the 'log' variable, it shows me:

```
IsDebugEnabled = false
IsErrorEnabled = true
IsFatalEnabled = true
IsInfoEnabled  = false
IsWarnEnabled  = true
```

From this I conclude that the configuration file is being read correctly.  My log4net configuration looks like this:

```
<log4net>
 <appender name="A1" type="log4net.Appender.OutputDebugStringAppender">

  <!-- A1 uses PatternLayout -->
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <!--<conversionPattern value="%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />-->
    <conversionPattern value="[MySite] %level %date{HH:mm:ss,fff} - %message%n" />        
  </layout>
 </appender>

 <root>
  <level value="WARN" />
  <appender-ref ref="A1" />
 </root>
</log4net>
```

When I add an additional FileAppender, the file it creates does indeed have the "hello" message in it.  Any clues why the VS debug output window isn't showing "hello"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using **DebugAppender** rather than OutputDebugStringAppender.

[DebugAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.15/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Appender_DebugAppender.htm) will end up as call to `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write` whereas OutputDebugStringAppender is calling unmanaged code and Visual Studio won't capture it (at least not by default and even then only when debugging, which means it won't work for your case).

Output from DebugAppender can also be captured using DebugView that is mentioned in the linked article, so I can't think of any reason he is are using OutputDebugStringAppender.

Comment: AARRGGHHH!!  So close, but so far!  DebugAppender works, and would be the perfect solution, except it forces all log-entries to be prefixed with the name of the logger.  I wish there was a property I could set on DebugAppender in configuration to tell it not to do that.